# Cannot get result set after reading output parameters

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, resultset, callable-statement

I am using java to access mssql 2012 DB

I have a stored procedure "procX" with takes only 1, (say named as @p1) in parameter and returns a single result set. It works fine unless I try to read the return value before I get the result set. Code is below. If I remove "//" and get return value, I get `null` as the result.

```
cs = con.prepareCall("{? = call procX(?)}");
cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
cs.setInt("p1", 1);
cs.execute();         
//cs.getInt(1);
rs = cs.getResultSet();
```

And even if I read the return value after I get the resultset, this closes the result set.

Is there a way to read return value without making it impossible to get the resultset?

And as far as I can see this situation is not restricted for return value and occurs for any other output parameters, too.

Comment: @tottiroma `CallableStatement` I guess.

Comment: yes i am using CallableStatement

Comment: what are you thinking about this `? = call procX(?)`? stored procedure doesn't return a value like a function does but in stored procedure you can set ouput parameter.

Comment: no. every stored procedure returns a 0 by default unless there is an error. also you can return any other value

Comment: How did this not err out completely? You're overwriting the first parameter and never setting the second.

Comment: "@p1" is the name of my input in storedprocedure. its index in call is 2. You can set it by index or by name. and the first index is belong to "return_value" as in "?= call...". this is the way to get return value of a stored procedure. it is output of type int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to get resultset(s) before reading any of the output parameters.

You can get the detail from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5576442/1519458

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting,

- firstly : I do not know what kind of driver are you using but try to
  change and provide us information will be the same behavior or no.
- secondly: if you are using Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server try
  to tune logger and see where is problem, this library using
  `java.util.logging.Logger` for logging before/after executing each
  operations.
- I think you are using java 7, try to downgrade and run it on Java 6, Why ? Because there is some interesting logic (with Closeable interface) in Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server for `getValue` method which called from `getInt` method.

Comment: I found the answer but cannot add it before 10 hours (my reputation is not enough to answer my own question)

Comment: Looks like you have to get resultset(s) before reading any of the output parameters.
You can get the detail from

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5576442/1519458

Comment: @araqnoon it is good explanation, related to driver implementation from Microsoft. The getInt method has next workflow, is getValue->getgetterparsms (or like this)->**close active stream** I think  this line is failed your Result Set.